# Completing Chemfig Scheme

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, structure

I'm currently writing a lab report using LaTeX and I'm tasked with rewriting one of the chemical reactions (in this instance isoborneol to camphor, reaction provided in pic). I have the basic structures down, however I'm unsure even after consulting the docs how to add the wedge and middle line into the aromatic structures. My current code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Isoborneol Oxidation Reaction To Camphor.\cite{chemfig,textbook}}
\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)-(<OH)----)}}{Isoborneol}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaOCl}}{Sodium\\Hypochlorite}
    \arrow{->[HOAc][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)-(=O)----)}}{Camphor}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaCl}}{Sodium\\Chloride}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop
\end{figure}
```

[image: Isoborneol to Camphor Synthesis Reaction]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Page 70 of the `chemfig` manual contains an example showing ththe camphor molecule in two different views, one of them quite similar to the one in your question. You may want to take a look ath the corresponding code.

Comment: Unrelated: in chemistry, reaction equations/schemes are usually not labeled as a "figure", but as a "scheme". To do so, you can use the `scheme` environment that is provided  a) by the `scheme` module of the `chemmacros` package of b) by the `chemscheme` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two versions, one inspired by the example in the `chemfig` manual, the other closer to the image in your question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Isoborneol Oxidation Reaction To Camphor.\cite{chemfig,textbook}}
\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)(<:[::120](-[::-100,0.7])(-[::100,0.7]))-(<OH)--(<:[::120])---)}}{Isoborneol}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaOCl}}{Sodium\\Hypochlorite}
    \arrow{->[HOAc][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)(<:[::120](-[::-100,0.7])(-[::100,0.7]))-(=O)--(<:[::120])---)}}{Camphor}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaCl}}{Sodium\\Chloride}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Isoborneol Oxidation Reaction To Camphor.\cite{chemfig,textbook}}
\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)(-[::100,1.075](-[::-70,0.8])(-[::110,0.8]))-(<OH)--(-[::140,1.075])---)}}{Isoborneol}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaOCl}}{Sodium\\Hypochlorite}
    \arrow{->[HOAc][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(-(-)(-[::100,1.075](-[::-70,0.8])(-[::110,0.8]))-(=O)--(-[::140,1.075])---)}}{Camphor}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NaCl}}{Sodium\\Chloride}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice and excellent work. +1

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to Isoborneol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-?[a](-)(-[2,,,,draw=none]-[0,0.4,,,draw=none]?[a]?[b](-[0,0.6])(-[4,0.6]))-(<OH)--?[b]--)}
\end{document}
```

[image]